# bscscan contract argument data decoding

Tags: solidity, etherscan, bsc, decoding, bscscan

Let's take a look at this tx:

https://bscscan.com/tx/0x9b7cde866e9fe9b9a1c636d0f9686ea5b1920c875d7fcd973baf847bc359c8a9

as you can see it's buying token through pancake swap:

```
0x0d0f397d6fb10213135cc384b245fab616f41865
```

however input data looks like this

```
0x2293db57000000000000000000000000bddc352a26d68bc82f9891e23b98bee662305cb5
```

from which we can easily work out (according to 100s of identical transactions with dynamic address argument) that this is the address that's passed to the contract function:

```
0xbddc352a26d68bc82f9891e23b98bee662305cb5
```

however these contract addresses do not match. Is this some default Solidity argument encoding? is there any way to decode this?

Answer (score 0):

The target contract (`0x890308ccaeb490a536ee70230f9183524b17f082`) isn't the official pancake swap contract. The contract isn't verified so it can be a a completely different contract that uses its own api and the parameter can be anything.

Don't assume a contract will do something from the transaction input alone. A contract can do anything.